# Printing a blank line in Lua

Tags: lua

Instead of:

```
print();
print("Hellow!");
```

Is there a way to print the blank line before `print("Hellow!")` without having to use a blank `print()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
print();
print("Hellow!");
```

You can replace the empty `print()` with a `\n` before the text:

```
print("\nHellow!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("");
print("Hellow!")
or
print("\nHellow!")
just like Alex said
```